# Cloudformation YAML not well-formed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloud formation template that I want to import some values from another template. Currently the other template exports a string by joining together an array (better way of doing this?).

In my template I want to import into I am getting the below error when trying to update my stack in the AWS console.

`Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 71, column 28)`

Here is lines 70 and 71 from my YAML file

```
SubnetId: 
        Fn::Select [ "0", [ Fn::Split: [ ",", Fn::ImportValue [ !Sub "${ExportPrefix}-SubNets"] ] ] ]
```

Have also tried this..

```
Fn::Select [ "0", [ {Fn::Split: [ ",", Fn::ImportValue [ {Fn::Sub "${ExportPrefix}-SubNets"}] ]} ] ]
```

I have checked and all spaces should be spaces and all tabs be tabs.

Answer (score 1):

The split function returns a list of strings. I believe encapsulating the function in a list is what is giving you the error. Have you tried removing the brackets around the split function? Something like:

```
!Select [ "0",  !Split [ "," , !ImportValue [ !Sub "${ExportPrefix}-SubNets" ] ] ]
```

Comment: Trying that doesn't seem to work, it gives the below error message. I also tried by switching to long form `Fn::` compared to `!` that passed validation but it didn't deploy. Ran into where it just said it couldn't find the subnet with the full string/line

Error message when using your suggesting without modification: `Template error: the attribute in Fn::ImportValue must be a string or a function that returns a string`